# Error event handling causes Read to not be called

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Below is my PartialView for a Kendo Grid. As of now, my Parts_Read action is NOT called. But, if I comment out

```
.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
```

Then everything works fine. Any ideas of why this is happening?

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using eRPortalDashboard.Models

@model PMPartsViewModel

@{
int PMNumber = Model.PMNumber;
string uniqueName = Model.PartsGrid.ID;//Regex.Replace(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "[^A-Za-z]+", "");
bool enableToolbar = Model.PartsGrid.EnableToolbar;
bool enablePageable = Model.PartsGrid.Pageable;
bool enableSortable = Model.PartsGrid.Sortable;
bool enableColumnMenu = Model.PartsGrid.EnableColumnMenu;
bool enableGroupable = Model.PartsGrid.Groupable;
bool enableColumnResizing = Model.PartsGrid.AllowColumnResizing;
bool enableScrolling = Model.PartsGrid.Scrollable;
bool enableSelection = Model.PartsGrid.Selectable;
}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PartViewModel>()
.Name(uniqueName)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.ItemNumber);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
})
    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
        toolBar.Custom().Text("Test Button").Url("#").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "testButton" });
    })
.Pageable(pager => pager
    .Input(false) //Using pageable.numeric and pageable.input at the same time is not recommended.
    .Numeric(true)
    .Info(true)
    .PreviousNext(true)
    .Refresh(true)
    .PageSizes(new object[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, "all" })
    .Enabled(enablePageable)
)
.Selectable(s => s.Mode(mode: GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Enabled(enableSelection))
.AllowCopy(enableSelection) //selectable needs to be enabled and set to multiple
.Sortable(s => s.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn).Enabled(enableSortable))
.ColumnMenu(c => c.Enabled(enableColumnMenu))
.Groupable(g => g.Enabled(enableGroupable))
.Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto").Enabled(enableScrolling))
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(enableColumnResizing))
    //.Events(events => events.DataBound(uniqueName + "_updateGrid").Change(uniqueName + "_updateGrid"))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(true)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))          
    .Read("Parts_Read", "PM", new { PMNumber = PMNumber })

)
)


<script type="text/javascript">
function error_handler(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Errors:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function () {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything showing up on the console?

Answer (score 0):

The main crux of my issue was the fact that error_handler was declared after my MVC code, thereby making it unable to bind to the method.

Apparently, with Kendo (maybe others), when using Partial Views, the javascript function must be declared BEFORE it is used in Razor syntax for that view.

see also: [telerik forum post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/action-filled-tabs-can't-find-scripts-from-partial-views)